# How to get the value of pressed button?

Tags: android, button

I am searching the solution, how to get the value of the button which is pressed.

When I try something like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button numb1 = ((Button)this.findViewById(R.id.numb1)); 
    numb1.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClickHandler(View v){
    String pressed = null;

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.numb1: 
            pressed=numb1.getText().toString();
            break;
            //OR
        case R.id.numb1: 
            pressed=R.id.numb1.getText().toString();
            break;  
     }

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Info").setMessage(pressed).setNeutralButton("Okey", null).show();       
}
```

Both cases in switch are unfortunately bad.

And I still can't get the value of the pressed button... Can you help me please with this problem yet?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Well guys, I am pretty new in this area, but I solved this problem like that:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
      int intID = view.getId();
      Button button = (Button) findViewById(intID);
      String message = button.getText().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`pressed=((Button)v).getText();` should do the job.

Also, let your activity implement `View.OnClickListener` and instead of onClickHandler() override the method `public void onClickHandler(View v)` with your implementation.

Comment: Thank for hint, MByD.
I am getting an error - I tried to repair it, but I don't know how. 

I'm getting "Multiple markers at this line - button cannot be resolved to a type (twice)"

Comment: you should import Button: `import android.widget.Button;` another tip: using eclipse you can import all needed classes by pressing `ctrl+shift+o`

Comment: Exactly that is weird - this "package" I have imported and still I'm getting that fault

Comment: My bad - it should be Button with capital B

Comment: Thanks a lot for hints, MByD. But I wondering where could by fault -- because I can't still get the value of button. In button tag is: 

<Button android:id="@+id/numb1" android:text="jedna" android:onClick="onClickHandler" />

but after using "((Button)v).getText().toString()" I can't getting the word "jedna" to variable "pressed"... What could by wrong yet?

Comment: I didn't look at it until now. Why don't you implement View.OnClickListener? I don't think you should use handler http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
Button sender = (Button)v;
sender.text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, is it possible you have two variables with the same name but different scopes causing you confusion?

In `onCreate`, you declare `Button numb1`, but `onClickHandler` appears to expect `numb1` to have also been declared outside of `onCreate`.  So, should `onCreate` just assign a value to `numb1`, instead of also declaring it?

At any rate, if you were to post a more complete code example, it may help others to identify the problem, instead of just guessing about how things are.

Comment: he is assigning to numb1 in onCreate() using findViewById() there is no conflict with R.id.numb1 since it's the id (int) of the button and declared in a totally different scope